# MacOSX El Capitan - Running bootstrap-vcpkg.sh results in a build stopped: subcommand failed, any solutions?

Tags: macos, terminal, install, script, sudo

When running sudo ./bootstrap-vcpkg.sh, the script stops resulting in a ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
I have no idea how to continue from here if anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated!

Error Message:

-- Build files have been written to: /vcpkg/toolsrc/build.rel
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/69] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/...ir/src/vcpkg/base/cofffilereader.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/vcpkglib.dir/src/vcpkg/base/cofffilereader.cpp.o 
/usr/local/bin/g++-6  -DDISABLE_METRICS=0 -I../include -O3 -DNDEBUG   -std=c++1z -MD -MT CMakeFiles/vcpkglib.dir/src/vcpkg/base/cofffilereader.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/vcpkglib.dir/src/vcpkg/base/cofffilereader.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/vcpkglib.dir/src/vcpkg/base/cofffilereader.cpp.o -c 
../src/vcpkg/base/cofffilereader.cpp

In file included from ../include/vcpkg/base/view.h:3:0,
                 from ../include/vcpkg/base/strings.h:7,
                 from ../include/vcpkg/base/checks.h:5,
                 from ../src/vcpkg/base/cofffilereader.cpp:3:

../include/vcpkg/base/span.h:32:53: error: 'is_const_v' is not a member of 'std'
         template>>
                                                     ^~~

../include/vcpkg/base/span.h:32:69: error: template argument 1 is invalid
         template>>
                                                                     ^

../include/vcpkg/base/span.h:32:72: error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
         template>>

^

In file included from ../include/vcpkg/base/files.h:3:0,
                 from ../include/vcpkg/base/cofffilereader.h:3,
                 from ../src/vcpkg/base/cofffilereader.cpp:4:

../include/vcpkg/base/expected.h:114:42: error: 'is_reference_v' is not a member of 'std'
         template>>
                                          ^~~

../include/vcpkg/base/expected.h:114:62: error: template argument 1 is invalid
         template>>
                                                              ^

../include/vcpkg/base/expected.h:114:65: error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
         template>>
                                                                 ^

../include/vcpkg/base/expected.h:115:46: error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token
         ExpectedT(T&& t, ExpectedLeftTag = {}) : m_t(std::move(t))
                                              ^

[2/69] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/...pkglib.dir/src/vcpkg/base/checks.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/vcpkglib.dir/src/vcpkg/base/checks.cpp.o 
/usr/local/bin/g++-6  -DDISABLE_METRICS=0 -I../include -O3 -DNDEBUG   -std=c++1z -MD -MT CMakeFiles/vcpkglib.dir/src/vcpkg/base/checks.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/vcpkglib.dir/src/vcpkg/base/checks.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/vcpkglib.dir/src/vcpkg/base/checks.cpp.o -c

../src/vcpkg/base/checks.cpp
In file included from ../include/vcpkg/base/view.h:3:0,
                 from ../include/vcpkg/base/strings.h:7,
                 from ../include/vcpkg/base/checks.h:5,
                 from ../src/vcpkg/base/checks.cpp:3:

../include/vcpkg/base/span.h:32:53: error: 'is_const_v' is not a member of 'std'
         template>>
                                                     ^~~

../include/vcpkg/base/span.h:32:69: error: template argument 1 is invalid
         template>>
                                                                     ^

../include/vcpkg/base/span.h:32:72: error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
         template>>

^

[3/69] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/vcpkg.dir/src/vcpkg.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/vcpkg.dir/src/vcpkg.cpp.o 
/usr/local/bin/g++-6  -DDISABLE_METRICS=0 -I../include -O3 -DNDEBUG   -std=c++1z -MD -MT CMakeFiles/vcpkg.dir/src/vcpkg.cpp.o -MF

CMakeFiles/vcpkg.dir/src/vcpkg.cpp.o.d -o

CMakeFiles/vcpkg.dir/src/vcpkg.cpp.o -c ../src/vcpkg.cpp

In file included from ../include/vcpkg/base/view.h:3:0,
                 from ../include/vcpkg/base/strings.h:7,
                 from ../include/vcpkg/base/checks.h:5,
                 from ../include/vcpkg/base/expected.h:3,
                 from ../include/vcpkg/base/files.h:3,
                 from ../src/vcpkg.cpp:24:

../include/vcpkg/base/span.h:32:53: error: 'is_const_v' is not a member of 'std'
         template>>
                                                     ^~~

../include/vcpkg/base/span.h:32:69: error: template argument 1 is invalid
         template>>
                                                                     ^

../include/vcpkg/base/span.h:32:72: error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
         template

std::enable_if_t>>

^

In file included from ../include/vcpkg/base/files.h:3:0,
                 from ../src/vcpkg.cpp:24:

../include/vcpkg/base/expected.h:114:42: error: 'is_reference_v' is not a member of 'std'
         template>>
                                          ^~~

../include/vcpkg/base/expected.h:114:62: error: template argument 1 is invalid
         template>>
                                                              ^

../include/vcpkg/base/expected.h:114:65: error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
         template>>
                                                                 ^

../include/vcpkg/base/expected.h:115:46: error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token
         ExpectedT(T&& t, ExpectedLeftTag = {}) : m_t(std::move(t))
                                              ^

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

I am trying to install vcpkg in order to install new library headers for c++, with this issue I have no idea how to continue.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg
enusre that: `gcc >= 7 or equivalent clang (on Linux)`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will be more than just one line.  Providing supporting info and links can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.